# How to find out what i'm doing wrong. Getting validation exception in timestream write Records with go sdk?

Tags: aws-sdk-go, amazon-timestream, aws-sdk-go-v2

As the title says, I'm trying to write a bunch of records to timestream, but I keep getting "ValidationException" without any further information, so I have no idea what should be fixed. The exact error response is:

> operation error Timestream Write: WriteRecords, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX, ValidationException:

It made me think that it was a multiline string and somehow the logging framework wasn't logging properly, but I tried splitting by \n and all I got was a size 1 list with the same text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the validation error is wrapped multiple errors deep. To get to the validation error message, you need the following:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/transport/http"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/timestreamwrite/types"
    "github.com/aws/smithy-go"
)
responseError := err.(*smithy.OperationError).Unwrap().(*http.ResponseError)
validationError := responseError.Unwrap().(*types.ValidationException)
fmt.Println(validationError.ErrorMessage())
```